# How can I effectively customize/style Ext.form.Slider?

Tags: sencha-touch, slider, extjs

I am trying to customize an Ext.form.Slider in Sencha Touch 1.1. This is my code:

```
de.letsdev.mySlider = new Ext.form.Slider({
    flex : 1,
    value : 0,
    centered : true,
    height : 10,
    maxHeight : 10,
    minValue : 0,
    maxValue : 20,
    disabled : true,
    disabledCls : '',
    componentCls : 'myClass'
});
```

The container does respect the set height but I expect the slider to scale according to that size which it doesn't. It is just cropped at 10px :/

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok my solution was to add this css:

```
. myClass .x-input-slider::after {
    height: 0.4em;
    top: 0.8em;
}
. myClass .x-thumb::before {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    top: 0.8em;
}
```

But this needed a little playing around and furthermore different configs for phone/tablet. A better solution would be appreciated.